# Should questions be edited to remove error-checking statements that dilute the code?

Tags: discussion, edits, code-formatting, code, formatting

In C one should rigorously perform null-checks, however doing so obfuscates the rest of the code making it more difficult to review. Is it okay to remove such statements from an original post solely to focus on blocks of code that may be causing the problem that the original poster describes?

For an example, while the code

```
// open input file 
FILE* inptr = fopen(infile, "r");

if (inptr == NULL) {
    printf("Could not open %s.\n", infile);
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}
```

is correct, when combined with several other such statements the attached code grows in size quickly. The following code

```
FILE* inptr = fopen(infile, "r");
```

carries with it the same semantics. And

```
FILE* inptr = fopen(infile, "r"); // null-check removed for brevity
```

should result in there not being any comments explaining that the author should have included a null-check following the `fopen` statement.

So, would it be egregious to modify submitted code to such an extent or is it encouraged? I could not find any question pertaining to this kind of editing here on Meta.

---

**Edit:** (why this is not a duplicate of [Edit code to reduce the used (vertical) space](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254671/edit-code-to-reduce-the-used-space))

Unlike [Edit code to reduce the used space](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254671/edit-code-to-reduce-the-used-space) this question pertains to *removing* code, although the semantics of the code remains the same.

Meanwhile [Edit code to reduce the used space](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254671/edit-code-to-reduce-the-used-space) is about formatting code to reduce the vertical space that is used but the code cannot be removed without changing the semantics of the (in this case) SQL query.

Comment: You shouldn't edit code in posts unless you are 100% sure the OP is on board. It's easy to correct a mistake that caused the error to appear by doing this. I understand where you are coming from, but it is frowned upon to do normally

Comment: No... don't remove error checking, that's a good indicator of whether or not the OP has checked for an error...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You as *author* of the post should remove code that is not directly related to the problem - [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) gives you guidance on that. You can provide link to complete code on reputable site (i.e. github/codepen/fiddle.net/...) to demonstrate that you understand what code is needed for production level programs.

**Do not** edit others posts to remove parts of code, especially questions. You can add comment to author of the post to cleanup code if you find it hard to read. It is author's responsibility to provide readable MCVE of exact problem they facing, there is generally no way to know which part is essential for particular case.

Note that most people proficient enough in given language/framework would be able to see past error/null checking functions without much trouble (assuming code is written according to language's/framework's standards).